# Why is the two-pass formula for variance more accurate than one-pass?

Tags: floating-accuracy, variance

The two-pass formula for variance, [image] is considered more numerically stable than the one-pass formula, [image][(reference)](http://cpsc.yale.edu/sites/default/files/files/tr222.pdf) The rationale given is that, assuming the variance is small, `\bar{x^2}` will be approximately equal to `\bar{x}^2`, and thus catastrophic cancellation will occur. However, for small variance, isn't it also true that `x_i` will be close to `\bar{x}` for many `i`, and thus that catastrophic cancellation could occur in the two-pass variance?

Answer (score 0):

Found a great answer here: https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/09/28/theoretical-explanation-for-numerical-results/

To directly respond to your question, catastrophic cancellation does not occur just because variance is small - it occurs because variance is small **relative to** the numbers we are dealing with. In the two-pass formula, we are only subtracting each value from the mean while in the one-pass formula, we are subtracting the squares, which is far larger than the variance.